# In hibernate, how to select results from one table while querying multiple tables

Tags: hibernate, join, inner-join

I want to create a Hibernate query that'll return a list of movies for which James Bond was played by an actor who is now more than 60 years old. (never mind the sillyness of this exemple)

I've tried many combinations with createQuery but can't set a condition on the join.

Also, another goal is I'd like the query to return a List<Movie> instead of List<String> or List<Whatever>.

More specifically, the SQL I'd like to run is as follows:

```
SELECT m.* FROM movies m
INNER JOIN movie_actors ma
    ON (ma.movie_id = m.id AND ma.role = 'James Bond')
INNER JOIN actors a
    ON (a.id = ma.actor_id AND a.age > 60)
```

For this purpose, I assume this table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE movies(
id            INTEGER          NOT NULL,
name          NVARCHAR2(100)    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_movies PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE movie_actors (
movie_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL,
actor_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL,
role      NVARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT fk_movies_actors_movie_id  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id)  REFERENCES movies,
CONSTRAINT fk_movies_actors_actor_id  FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actors
);

CREATE TABLE actors (
  id         INTEGER         NOT NULL, 
  firstname  NVARCHAR2(50)   NOT NULL, 
  lastname   NVARCHAR2(50)   NOT NULL,
  age        INTEGER       NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT pk_actors  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding the relationships, the HQL query can be as below. We need to replace the table names with the Java Bean names and column names with the properties. Also add a constructor to `Movie` class to set the `id` and `name` that will give you the result as `List<Movie>` instead of `List<Object[]>`.

```
SELECT new Movie (m.id, m.name) FROM movies m
INNER JOIN MovieActors ma
    ON (ma.movieId = m.id AND ma.role = 'James Bond')
INNER JOIN actors a
    ON (a.id = ma.actorId AND a.age > 60)
```

Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) or some examples [here](http://jyops.blogspot.in/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

two tables

1) CivilDashboard

2) ProjectSubcompChild

```
from CivilDashboard cd1 
where cd1.civilDbPkid in ( select cd.civilDbPkid as civilDbPkid 
                           from ProjectSubcompChild sc, CivilDashboard cd 
                           where sc.subcompChildPkid = cd.projectSuncompChildPkid)
```